# WinJS - Disable ListView animation when items update

Tags: listview, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am working on a ListView which get refreshed every 2 min.
The listview uses multiple templates (assigned using custom itemTemplate function)

As I am having multiple templates in list view I cannot simply update the data using dataSource.change function.
I have to reset the dataSource so that based on latest data it should be able to pick the correct template again.

But when I reassign the dataSource a distracting flicker animation occurs. I want to get rid of that animation.

```
var listView = element.querySelector('.my-list-view').winControl;
var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(data);
listView.itemTemplate = function (itemPromise) {
    return itemPromise.then(function (item) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        var itemTemplate;
        switch (item.data.status) {
            case "Final":
                itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".final-template");
                break;

            case "NotFinal":
                itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".not-final-template");
                break;
        }

        itemTemplate.winControl.render(item.data, container);
        container.style.height = '120px';
        container.style.width = '380px';
        return container;
    });
};
listView.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
listView.addEventListener("contentanimating", function (e) { e.preventDefault() });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to reset the data? If you are using multiple templates, your itemTemplate render function is called when the item needs to be rendered -- and if you've changed the item and cause it to be added, or replaced in the underlying data set, the listview can react to this can call your item template. This will be much more performant than asking the list view to render **all** your data again -- especially on low end devices such as ARM.

For details on an itemTemplate render function, see the section 'Displaying items with a Template or render function' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212598.aspx).

However, if this still doesn't work for you, you can disable animations in the list view by handling the "contentanimating" event, and calling `preventDefault()` on the event object when it's raised. E.g.

```
var myListview = /* get listview control some how */
myListView.addEventListener("contentanimating", function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
```

Remember to detach the listener if your code is longer lived than the listview instance.

Comment: I would also prefer to replace the content rather than assigning the new dataSource to the list if it allows me to pick the correct template while replacing. I tried the preventDefault for contentanmiating as you mentioned. It reduces the flicker but does not completely eliminate it. I will post the sample code I am using in the post.

Comment: Manipulating your "list" instance to add & remove the item that changes should give you what you want.

Comment: The code posted above is inside the success handler of an XHR call which gets auto refreshed using `setInterval`.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you post sample code for manipulating list instance. That will be really helpful.

Comment: preventDefault on contentanmating does not work if the listview use GridLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable animations at any time using `WinJS.UI.disableAnimations();` and then enable them again when your reset is complete, ased on the `ListView` `LoadingState`.